# Create a field to type in name of body class

Tags: views, theming

I want to create a field where I can put in what will be a class on the body of the node that I'm creating.  The picture below depicts my local and live environments:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: what version of drupal are you using?

Comment: I'm using 7.14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found a module which did just what I wanted.
If anyone else are looking for an answer to my question, you can check out this module:
https://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class

It allows you to enter a class name from the editing page. You can select if you want the class to be appended to the body, node etc.

Comment: Marked as useful answer because you found your own solution, and it works. Good to know this module exists however, I would consider using one of the other solutions as well. Adding modules for trivial tasks slows Drupal down and you can end up with a lot of them really quick doing things that way.

Answer (score 2):

Johan, if the only thing out of sync between your live and local environments are the node nids, you can do this with css like so:

```
/* this will target both and will work on both environments if the other nid
   does not exist in the other environment */

.node-page-1521,
.node-page-1497 {
  /* whatever CSS you need here */
}
```

as Drupal puts the class `node-page-NID` in the body of each page created for a specific node.  If the "other nid" exists in the local or live site, then you will have to get a bit fancier, but this does show that Drupal can target specific node pages.

Another way would be to use [hook_preprocess_html()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) a custom module or theme, eg, something along the lines of:

```
function YOURMODULE_OR_THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  if (isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->nid == THE_NID_YOU_WANT) {
    $variables['classes_array'][]='SPECIAL_CLASS';
  }

}
```

Just realize the above snippet is dull ax; eg, you would probably want to do something better than just hard coding a nid in there, eg storing it in a variable specific to the machine (look into [variable_get()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) and creating an admin form for your theme/module).

If it is something else, eg, you want to have a field that allows the user to somehow specify something special in the display about this (and other similar nodes), you can certainly do that as well above, eg, look at that field instead of the nid and then add a class if it has a certain value.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that I can style a certain page using it's unique node ID. That is the problem here and that is not what I'm asking for advice to do. I can't use this technique since the live and local versions are not in sync, thus will have different node ID's. 

Targeting both the local and live node id's is not an option since I will then actually target another live page node which I do not want.

What I want is a field where the user (=me) can enter a value in the backend. That value will then be appended as a class on the body of the node. This can't be that complicated, really?

Comment: glad you found a module to do what you need; it does in its preprocess_html() precisely what I suggested in my last paragraph above, so, no, it's not that complicated.

Comment: Good information, I much prefer to implement my own code instead of bloating the install with additional modules. I think my method would also be quite clean too. (in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

Even if this was possible, it is not good practice. Use your CSS files to add styles to nodes. If you inspect the DOM elements of your node, you will see there are plenty of ways to single out the body without the use of your suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure. I develop on a local machine and that version is not in perfect sync with the live version. Thus I can't use node-specific classes to target a specific page. And if I only want to target a single page, then I see no other really specific class to use.

Comment: I completely disagree. Show me an example DOM and I will show you.

Comment: Ok, this image shows the DOM of the same page on local and live. 

http://i.imgur.com/4PGOTOF.jpg

How do I target this one page using a single body class?

Comment: .page-node-1521 is unique to that node.

Comment: No, you are obviously not understanding. .page-node-1521 is a unique page on live, and ANOTHER page on local. I can't style my page using that class since I will style another page on my live version.

Comment: Actually, much simpler than that module or adding new classes. You just use some php and target each site, dev and live with a proper CSS file. This way you don't have to manage new classes and grow your CSS file even more.

Comment: Indeed, the answer to this question specifically appears to be a hack instead of a feature. In pantheon and other environments it is easy to look at a $_SERVER variable for these types of issues and then do things whether in dev/test/prod.

Comment: It's not a problem to use a CSS file to manage my styling. That is what CSS is for. Of course I want to use a proper CSS file to add styles to my nodes, the problem was targeting a unique node when the node ID's are different on local, preprod and production. Also, I wanted the method to be easy to do and easy to repeat since this will be something that I have to do a lot of times.