# How to add CSS classes to buttons of Drupal Commerce checkout forms?

Tags: commerce, theming

How can I add a bootstrap `btn-success` class to the Drupal Commerce Checkout button in the cart form?

The *Update cart* button already has `btn-info` but I can't find `btn-info` anywhere in the code.

If would also like to adapt buttons in other parts as I expect `btn-success` buttons to lead to higher conversion.

Bootstrap has great classes, I don't want to fiddle with CSS to try and recreate that, I just want to use the Bootstrap classes.

I'm okay with adding some PHP code to my theme's `template.php`, probably `_form_alter()` and this is probably the way to do it. But how exactly?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According that you have default `views_form_commerce_cart_form_default` form for your cart, this should do the job. Put the following lines in a custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_form_commerce_cart_form_default_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['checkout']['#attributes']['class'] = array('btn-success');
}
```

If not ok, check the ID of your form with

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id); 
}
```

and apply the same above snippet with function `MYMODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter`.

**EDIT :** to apply `btn-success` to *Continue* buttons of the cart, checkout, review pages:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {

    case 'views_form_commerce_cart_form_default':
      $form['actions']['checkout']['#attributes']['class'] = array('btn-success');
      break;

    case 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout':
    case 'commerce_checkout_form_review':
      $form['buttons']['continue']['#attributes']['class'] = array('btn-success');
      break;   
  }
}
```

To do it yourself next time : in your `hook form alter()` module, check the `form_id`, `dsm($form);` and browse the *dsm tree* to find your needle...

Comment: Do you mean: `$form['actions']['checkout']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-success';` ... a developer doesn't necessarily know if the parent modules sets a css class now -- or will need to in a future release of the module, so custom classes should be appended to those that exist already.

Comment: @tenken either with `$form['actions']['checkout']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-success';` or `$form['actions']['checkout']['#attributes']['class'] = array('btn-success');` the `btn-success` custom class is appended to existing ones. I understand what you suggest but it seems that Drupal does not overwrite the class array, but adds the custom value in any case... Do you agree?

Comment: I'm not sure, I thought in a past project I had overwritten css classes by accident -- maybe @Clive can confirm?

Comment: It works for the cart, but not for the checkout forms, `commerce_checkout_form_checkout`. This works for the `cart_form` but not for the `checkout_form`s: `if (in_array($form_id, array('views_form_commerce_cart_form_default', 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout', 'commerce_checkout_form_review'))) {
    $form['actions']['checkout']['#attributes']['class'] = array('btn-success');
  }
`

Comment: Unfortunately `dpm($form)` is merely giving my `Array()`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working well now! I had done this kind of stuff before but looks like `dpm`/`dsm` is broken on this site. One more thing to fix.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to add classes to generated content like that. It is doable but generally not necessary. See this [related post and comments](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100257/create-a-field-to-type-in-name-of-body-class/100270) for some light on this subject.

You can target the buttons with CSS using a cascade.

The cart page has the body class `.page-cart` and the form buttons has a class `.form-actions`. So, target the buttons with `input`like so:

```
.page-cart .form-actions input { some css here }
```

If you are being overridden, let me know in a comment and I can help with that. A link would be useful.

Comment: I want to use the `btn-success` class, I don't want to target the buttons with CSS.

Comment: If you want to add CSS to the elements of a page created by Drupal Commerce, you have two options. Write a module to override the theme template or use jQuery to parse the DOM onload and add the CSS.

Comment: Or third options, the answer by Kojo that I thnik is the straightforward, write a simple module that implements the right form alter hook,

Answer (score 0):

adding css to the buttons on the cart is the same as adding css to anything else. look at the page where the button is. right click on the button and select inspect element. The browser will display the DOM tree at the position of that element. Look for a point in that element or its parent elements that you can use to target that element. type up your css in your style sheet to target that element. This is how you should do it for anything in drupal. let drupal do the hard work of rendering the page then look at what it makes and style from the output.

Answer (score 0):

With COMMERCE Version: 7.x-1.13 :

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {   

   if ($form_id = 'form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart') {    
         $form['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-success';
   }

}
```